# How to split a Japanese character string on the basis of first occurrence of a numeric character?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a Japanese character string which contains Japanese as well as numeric character .i want to split the string on the basis of the first occurrence of the numeric character in string. For example,

```
String value = "上目黒１丁目２－３"; 
after split
value1 = "上目黒; 
value2 = "１丁目２－３";
```

For English string i'm able to achieve this using following piece of code.

```
String s = "abc1w2";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^\\d]+)(.*)").matcher(s);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());
        System.out.println("sep");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

But it's not working for Japanese characters.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use your own approach with the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag that will make the `\d` Unicode aware: `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^\\d]+)(.*)", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(s);`. See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GxC1Ei).

However, you may use a mere `split`:

```
String value = "上目黒１丁目２－３";
String[] res = value.split("(?U)(?=\\d)", 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/OVrukX)

The `.split("(?U)(?=\\d)", 2)` will split your string into 2 parts (see the `2` argument) with the `(?=\d)` Unicode-aware pattern (see the `(?U)`, a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` embedded flag option), matching a location before a digit (the `(?=....)` is a positive lookahead that only checks for a pattern to the right, but does not consume the string as it  is a zero-width assetion).